# hide div, show another... then hide, show another on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a div hide and then show the next div when the image in the div is clicked. When it is clicked again, hide that div and load the next one, etc.

The below works, but realize it's not pretty. What's the better way to do this, and without using inline javascript?

I'm also trying to add a "next" button that will hide the div and show the next dive... so the user can load the next item without clicking the `a href` in the div.

Thanks!

```
function replace( hide, show ) {
  document.getElementById(hide).style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(show).style.display="block";
}
```

Body...

```
<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace('div1','div2')"><a href="link1.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/a.jpg"></a></div>
<div id = "div2" style="display:none" onclick = "replace('div2','div3')"><a href="link2.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/b.jpg"></a></div>
<div id = "div3" style="display:none" onclick = "replace('div3','div4')"><a href="link3.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/c.jpg"></a></div>
<div id = "div3" style="display:none" onclick = "replace('div4','div5')"><a href="link4.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/.jpg"></a></div>
...
```

Comment: You could use the `toggle()` function in jQuery, it will show hidden elements and hide visible ones.

Comment: But if you want the images to perform an 'advance' after a click, than why you have them wrapped inside an `a` element that is linkable to an other page using `target="_blank"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uyaren/3/edit)*

But if you want the images to perform an 'advance' after a click, than why you have them wrapped inside an `a` element that is linkable to an other page using `target="_blank"` ?

In the meanwhile here is the simplified HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">  
  <a href="link1.html" target="_blank"><img src="img1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="link2.html" target="_blank"><img src="img2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="link3.html" target="_blank"><img src="img3.jpg"></a>
  <a href="link4.html" target="_blank"><img src="img4.jpg"></a>  
</div>
```

...and this couple of jQ/javascript lines:

```
var i = 0;                       // set desired starting one // zero based                         
var N = $('#gallery >*').length; // get number of childrens

function advance(){
    $('#gallery >*').hide().eq(i++%N).show();
}
advance();

$('#next').click( advance );
```

---

Using this script you can easily trigger the `advance` function clicking your images too, but than you have to prevent the `anchor` click behavior using inside the function `return false` :

### *[jsBin demo with clickable images](http://jsbin.com/uyaren/4/edit)*

```
var i = 0;                            
var N = $('#gallery >*').length;

function advance(){
  $('#gallery >*').hide().eq(i++%N).show();
  return false;   // remove that line to make the gallery advance but the same time go to the desired link-page
}
advance();

$('#next, #gallery >*').click( advance ); // comma separate the elements that will trigger the function
```

---

If you want a more 'fancy' effect here you go:

### *[jsBin demo with fade effect](http://jsbin.com/uyaren/5/edit)*

The code:

```
var i = 0;                            
var N = $('#gallery >*').length;

$('#gallery >*').hide().eq(i++%N).show(); // the initial adjustment (on DOM ready)

function advance(){
  $('#gallery >*').stop().fadeTo(900,0).eq(i++%N).stop().fadeTo(900,1);
}

$('#next, #gallery >*').click( advance );    // trigger the fade advance/effect function
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost exactly what I'm looking for. So when the user clicks the image and it opens the new window, I'd like the image to advance to the next one. That way when they come back to the parent window, it is already advanced for them. Make sense?

Comment: @user1373779 I added another demo, have you seen it? You can click on images too now. (or I don't understand well your comment...)

Comment: Thanks again! With your second demo, I'm trying to get the image to advance when you click the image (like you have), but also follow the `a href target="_blank"` so it opens a new window and goes to a url (say google.com for example).

Comment: If you want to achieve that, just remove `return false;` It will than bring you to the desired page, making the gallery advance to the next one

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! Is there a way to make the "next" button only work up til the last div, and then redirect with a `window.location`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, given that jQuery appears to be an option:

```
$('div').not(':first').hide();
$('div a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this).closest('div'),
            duration = 1200;
        if (that.next('div').length){
            that.fadeOut(duration,
                         function(){
                             that.next('div').fadeIn(duration);
                         });
        }
    });​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BYqrk/).

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP, below:

> Anyway to do this so when you click the image the a href target=_blank works?

Sort of, yes. But assuming that all you want is for a new window to open up in response to clicking the `a` (and to open that window to the `href` from that `a`), then simply use `window.open()`:

```
$('div').not(':first').hide();
$('div a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newWin = window.open(this.href,'newWindow'),
            that = $(this).closest('div'),
            duration = 1200;
        if (that.next('div').length){
            that.fadeOut(duration,
                         function(){
                             that.next('div').fadeIn(duration);
                         });
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BYqrk/1/).

---

**Edited** to improve the script a little, as per Roko's comment that a 'loop would be nice' (which I misunderstood initially, but now assume that he meant to move from the last image to the first, rather than simply failing/stopping):

```
$('div').not(':first').hide();
$('div a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();        
        var newWin = window.open(this.href,'newWin'),
            that = $(this).closest('div'),
            duration = 1200;
        if (that.next('div').length){
            that.fadeOut(duration,
                         function(){
                             that.next('div').fadeIn(duration);
                         });
        }
        else {
            that.fadeOut(duration,
                         function(){
                             that.prevAll('div:last').fadeIn(duration);
                         });
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BYqrk/2/).

References:

- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Comment: Um..? I honestly don't know whether I'm missing a criticism, or just not understanding your comment. Have I done something hideous?

Comment: I like this, thanks. Anyway to do this so when you click the image the `a href target=_blank` works?

Comment: @David noooo c'mon, the code is seriously nice, I just created a demo fiddle and was surprized that a loop (yes, was not mentioned in the Q) was "missing"... just cause I wanted to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Roko: agreed! I can't believe I hadn't thought of that...thanks! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for this. Is there a way to integrate a "next" button, to skip to the next image without clicking on the image (like Roko's script)?  Also, any way to make it so the last div img will redirect `window.location` to a different URL on mouse click, while also still utilizing the `window.open` to the a href location? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

give all your divs an `onclick="hideMeShowNext(this)"`

and define the function

```
<script>

function hideMeShowNext( element )
{

element.style.display = 'none'
element.nextSibling.style.display = 'block'

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you somehow expect the links to work, and then on the new page show the selected image?

If not :

```
var elems = $('div[id^="div"]');
elems.not(':first').hide();

elems.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    elems.hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1"><a href="link1.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/a.jpg"></a></div>
<div id="div2"><a href="link2.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/b.jpg"></a></div>
<div id="div3"><a href="link3.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/c.jpg"></a></div>
<div id="div4"><a href="link4.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/.jpg"></a></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use two functions at the same time

```
<script>
function hideMeShowNext( element )
{
element.style.display = 'none'
element.nextSibling.style.display = 'block'
}
</script>

then render this anywhere in your page//you can change <A> to <Div>
<a href="" onclick="hideMeShowNext('first');hideMeShowNext('second');">Click Me</a>
```

if it doesnt work, then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfnction() {
hideMeShowNext('first');
hideMeShowNext('second');
}
</script>

<a href="" onclick="myfunction();"> blabla </a>
```